# How to guarantee column with consecutive number fields after deleting rows?

Tags: java, database, typescript, row

Having a table **items** with a column **position**(int) which is not PK, how can one achieve always consecutive values from 1 to the number of items after performing any item(row) deletion?

(*Java* or *TypeScript* approaches)

Comment: Please add some example data… What have you tried so far? I don't really get the problem: How do you expect data to be consecutive if a row (maybe from the middle of a sorted set) is removed? 1, 2, 4, 5 --> not consecutive anymore.

Comment: If the row with position attribute 3 is deleted, then the row 4 should become 3 and the row 5 should become 4 ..

Comment: Ah, ok… you want the data attributes to be rearranged after deletion. How does an item look? Do you have them in a `List` or `Map` in Java?

Comment: I do have a list `List<Item>`

Comment: Only the position is important and a PK id..

Comment: Well, first idea would be to just sort the `List<Item>` and reset all positions in an iteration afterwards. I try to create an example in Java.

Comment: I reworded your question title a bit to make it more clear, but I think your question is essentially too broad. A) you shouldnt ask for TWO languages here, decide which one matters more to you B) you better include some attempts of yours. Just dropping requirements and asking others to do the heavy lifting often does not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very simple approach, just remove the `Item` and rearrange the positions of the remaining `Item`s

That can be done in a method that takes the `List<Item>` and the `Item` which is to be removed.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        // put some test items into the list
        Item first = new Item(1, 1);
        Item second = new Item(2, 2);
        Item third = new Item(3, 3);
        Item fourth = new Item(4, 4);
        Item fifth = new Item(5, 5);
        items.add(first);
        items.add(second);
        items.add(third);
        items.add(fourth);
        items.add(fifth);

        // print the list once:
        System.out.println("Original list:");

        items.forEach((Item item) -> {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        });

        // remove one item using the rearranging method
        removeItemFrom(third, items);

        // print the result
        System.out.println("After rearrangement:");

        items.forEach((Item item) -> {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        });
    }

    public static void removeItemFrom(Item itemToBeRemoved, List<Item> items) {
        // first remove the desired item
        items.remove(itemToBeRemoved);

        // then sort (if it is already sorted, skip this step)
        // items.sort(/*otherwise sort with a Comparator of your choice*/);

        // define a counter
        int positioner = 1;

        // give every item in the sorted list a new position
        for(Item item : items) {
            // re-set position with a counter
            item.setPosition(positioner);
            positioner++;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is somehow helpful.